# how to select and organize the date from horizontal to vertical in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table structure as below.

```
    Materialno  |   Rate    |   Month
    s1          |   20      |   jan
    s1          |   30      |   feb
    s1          |   40      |   mar
    s2          |   20      |   jan
    s2          |   30      |   feb
```

I need to query and convert table structure into below format

```
  Materialno    | jan_rate  |feb_rate   |mar_rate
        s1      |   20      |   30      |   40
        s2      |   20      |   30      |
```

is this possible in hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
select Materialno, 
       max(if(Month='jan',Rate,0)) as jan_rate,
       max(if(Month='feb',Rate,0)) as feb_rate,
       max(if(Month='mar',Rate,0)) as mar_rate
       from inputTable group by Materialno;
```

This works assuming you have one rate value per month per material No', otherwise max will be chosen.

Comment: Will it consume more time when I am running for one year. Yeah I have more than one rate per month per materialno

Comment: It should be about the same amount of time. If you have more than one rate, the code will only keep the max value. You can change to another aggregation functions (such as `avg`)